Data transfer using different transport protocols
Can we send data from publisher side using a particular protocol like UDP and receive data from the subscriber side using another protocol like TCP?
I was running a ros2 publisher node with transport protocol selected as UDP and ros2 subscriber node with transport protocol selected as PCIe...I was not able to subscribe the message sent by the publisher. Why?
